# "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error" when installing Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a new disk

Tags: boot, system-installation, ssd

I recently got a new disk (Western Digital blue 250GB SATA) and I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 on it.

The first time I tried installing from a USB key (created from Ubuntu's startup disk creator), I choose to install automatically on the SSD and the installation went well until it displayed the message: "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error". This was the only disk on the PC.

The second time I tried I had the new SSD in the port 0 with the failed install and the old HDD on port 1 with an install of Ubuntu 20.04.3, but the same thing happened again.
This time I choose to automatically erase de SSD and install.

Finally, I tried manual partitioning, which worked but when trying to boot it doesn't recognized it. Only if I press F10 to manually chose the booting location I can boot it.

Some maybe relevant info:
processor: Intel core i5-2400k
Motherboard: Intel dh67bl

I would be happy to provide any other information necessary.

Comment: Are you by any chance booting (and consequently installing) in Legacy mode (AKA CSM AKA "BIOS")?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have UEFI boot enabled on the BIOS, is that what you mean? I am not well versed on booting. Also I have fast boot disabled if that's relevant.

Comment: All computers at least since 2012 have UEFI so UEFI mode is enabled. But almost all also allow Legacy by default. Then, with a USB installer made with any tool except Rufus, that boots either way, it depends on the how it is booted. Better to disable Legacy/CSM to assure it always boots (and installs) in UEFI mode.